# Page blinking while clicking on it | jQuery .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Two questions.
When i'm loading to `div` file via jQuery `.load()` 
`$('.class').click(function(){
    $(this).load("file.php");
});` 
`file.php` is loading properly, but whenever i click on it (doesn't matter where, just in `file.php` zone), page is blinking. Something like page refresh on click. Is there a way to prevent that?
Also the position of this page is always relative to div. Why doesn't `position: absolute;` on `body` in seperate css file for `file.php` work for `file.php`? I want to reset the position of `file.php` to be on top of website (not z-index). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code

```
$('.class').click(function(){
    $(this).load("file.php");
});
```

says any time you click in that div, (re)load the contents.

You may want to use jQuery's [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method instead

```
$('.class').one("click", function(){
    $(this).load("file.php");
});
```

which will only execute the first time you click inside the div.

As to position, we'd need to see code. Possibly one of your parent elements has `position: relative`?

Comment: Ahhh tunnel vision in css file. Had twice position, one for `relative`, one for `absolute`, tho the `relative` was somewhere hidden in the middle of `div`, after `absolute`. Thanks for showing the way for fix with this `.one()'. Didn't think about it.

Comment: Yeah, that'll do it. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Easy way.

```
$('.class').one("click", function(){
    $(this).load("file.php");
});
```

Also is better to use `.ajax()` for this to have more options and better control.

`.load()` sometimes can first destroy content and then load new one. If you load bunch amount of data, that can made blink effect.

Comment: Hmmm, is there any performance difference between `.ajax()` and `.load()`?

Comment: Well, if you optimize and use only basic stufs in `.ajax()` function - no. You can just use `.ajax().done()` to finish your request and rewrite your element in done function. Is mutch better then success callback inside ajax function.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your replies :)